# ¿Cómo cargar el combo de días en JavaScript a partir de un select de año y mes?

Tags: javascript

Estoy realizando un ejercicio que me solicita: "crea tres selects: uno para año, otro para mes y otro para día. Has de mostrar el número de días correcto para el mes y año y luego crear un objeto Date para mostrar por pantalla la fecha seleccionada". Bien, he aquí mi código HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Básico 5 Fechas</title>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
    <!-- Crea una página dónde a partir de tres selects con el día del mes, el mes y el año puedas construir un objeto Date,
    para mostrarlo por pantalla en formato local. Observa qué pasa cuando introduces una fecha que no existe. Invierte los selects para ponerlos año/mes/día. Cuando elija el mes, que me los cargue con el número de días que tiene el mes. Se valida que haya año seleccionado, luego mes seleccionado y luego días. -->
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Este pequeño programa te mostrará la fecha escogida por pantalla</h2>

    <form>
        <select id="anio" onchange="cargarNumeroDias()"></select>
        <select id="mes" onchange="cargarNumeroDias()"></select>
        <select id="dia"></select>
        <button type="button" id="button" onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar en pantalla la fecha</button>
    </form>

    <div id="output"></div>






</body>
</html>
```

Y he aquí mi código en JavaScript:

```
function cargarPagina() {

    let anioMinimo = 1900;
    let anioMaximo = 2020;
    let anio = 0;

    let comboAnio = document.getElementById("anio");

    for (let i = anioMinimo; i <= anioMaximo; i++) {
        let option = document.createElement("option"); //Con esto creo la etiqueta option
        option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)

        let optionText = document.createTextNode(i); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
        option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
        comboAnio.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboAnio, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta



    }

    let array = [
        "enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"
    ]; //Le meto todos los meses y hago lo mismo

    let comboMes = document.getElementById("mes");

    for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        let option=document.createElement("option"); //Con esto le creo la etiqueta option
        option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)
        let itexto="";

        switch(i){
            case 0: itexto="enero";
            break;
            case 1: itexto="febrero";
            break;
            case 2: itexto="marzo";
            break;
            case 3: itexto="abril";
            break;
            case 4: itexto="mayo";
            break;
            case 5: itexto="junio";
            break;
            case 6: itexto="julio";
            break;
            case 7: itexto="agosto";
            break;
            case 8: itexto="septiembre";
            break;
            case 9: itexto="octubre";
            break;
            case 10: itexto="noviembre";
            break;
            case 11: itexto="diciembre";
            break;
        }


        let optionText=document.createTextNode(itexto); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
        option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
        comboMes.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboMes, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta  
    }

    //Cuando pulso año o mes lanza un evento Onchange que calcula el número de días del mes (CalcularDiasMes).
    //Tras esto, creo un objeto Date con los valores del select.
    //Ya con el objeto Date, lo muestro en pantalla con date.InnerHTML() y hecho



}

function cargarNumeroDias(){

    let comboDia=document.getElementById("dia");

    let numeroDias=calcularDiasMes(anio, mes); //Con esto cojo el número de días para el mes y el año en concreto
    let numeroDiasArray=[numeroDias]; //Creo un array con el número de días


    for (let i= 0; i < numeroDiasArray.length; i++) {
        let option=document.createElement("option"); //Con esto le creo la etiqueta option
        option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)
        let optionText=document.createTextNode(i); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
        option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
        comboDia.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboDia, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta  

    }

}




function calcularDiasMes(anio, mes) {

    let numeroDias = -1;

    switch (mes) {
        case 1:
        case 3:
        case 5:
        case 7:
        case 8:
        case 10:
        case 12:
            numeroDias = 31;
            break;
        case 4:
        case 6:
        case 9:
        case 11:
            numeroDias = 30;
            break;
        case 2:


            if ((anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || (anio % 100 == 0 && anio % 400 == 0)) { //Con esto sé si es bisiesto o no
                numeroDias = 29;
            } else {
                numeroDias = 28;
            }
            break;

    }

    return numeroDias;
}


window.onload = cargarPagina; //Para que esta función se cargue cuando se inicia la página
```

El caso es que depurando cuando selecciono año o mes, se me carga un 0 en el select de los días, y ya he observado que esto se debe a que let ComboDias=calcularDiasMes(anio,mes) me devuelve un valor -1. Pero me he bloqueado y no sé como seguir. ¿Alguna ayuda para arreglar este código? Muchas gracias :)

Comment: hola te falto el = a el for del mes por que si lo deja solo menor que el array te sale de enero a noviembre

Answer (score 1):

Te devolvía -1 (que era el valor con el que lo inicializas) porqué no sabía que mes y año era. De hecho, es uno de los varios errores de código que te he solucionado. Cuando querías pasarle el valor del mes y año a la función calcularDiasMes, no le pasabas el valor, sino que le pasabas el objeto entero. Por eso te devolvía -1.

Además, a la hora de recorrer los días, lo hacías a través de un array. No hace falta, teniendo el total de días, ese es el valor que cuenta.

Finalmente, cada vez que selecciones un año y/o mes, borra los días para que ponga los días correctos según la combinación, de este modo evitarás tener días repetidos o que se solapen los días en el combo de días.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Básico 5 Fechas</title>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
        <!-- Crea una página dónde a partir de tres selects con el día del mes, el mes y el año puedas construir un objeto Date,
        para mostrarlo por pantalla en formato local. Observa qué pasa cuando introduces una fecha que no existe. Invierte los selects para ponerlos año/mes/día. Cuando elija el mes, que me los cargue con el número de días que tiene el mes. Se valida que haya año seleccionado, luego mes seleccionado y luego días. -->
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Este pequeño programa te mostrará la fecha escogida por pantalla</h2>

        <form>
            <select id="anio" onchange="cargarNumeroDias()"></select>
            <select id="mes" onchange="cargarNumeroDias()"></select>
            <select id="dia"></select>
            <button type="button" id="button" onclick="mostrar()">Mostrar en pantalla la fecha</button>
        </form>

        <div id="output"></div>

        <script>
            function cargarPagina() {
                let anioMinimo = 1900;
                let anioMaximo = 2020;
                let anio = 0;

                let comboAnio = document.getElementById("anio");

                for (let i = anioMinimo; i <= anioMaximo; i++) {
                    let option = document.createElement("option"); //Con esto creo la etiqueta option
                    option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)

                    let optionText = document.createTextNode(i); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
                    option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
                    comboAnio.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboAnio, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta
                }

                let array = [
                    "enero", "febrero", "marzo", "abril", "mayo", "junio", "julio", "agosto", "septiembre", "octubre", "noviembre", "diciembre"
                ]; //Le meto todos los meses y hago lo mismo

                let comboMes = document.getElementById("mes");

                for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    let option=document.createElement("option"); //Con esto le creo la etiqueta option
                    option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)
                    let itexto="";

                    switch(i){
                        case 1: itexto="enero";
                        break;
                        case 2: itexto="febrero";
                        break;
                        case 3: itexto="marzo";
                        break;
                        case 4: itexto="abril";
                        break;
                        case 5: itexto="mayo";
                        break;
                        case 6: itexto="junio";
                        break;
                        case 7: itexto="julio";
                        break;
                        case 8: itexto="agosto";
                        break;
                        case 9: itexto="septiembre";
                        break;
                        case 10: itexto="octubre";
                        break;
                        case 11: itexto="noviembre";
                        break;
                        case 12: itexto="diciembre";
                        break;
                    }

                    let optionText=document.createTextNode(itexto); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
                    option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
                    comboMes.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboMes, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta  
                }

                //Cuando pulso año o mes lanza un evento Onchange que calcula el número de días del mes (CalcularDiasMes).
                //Tras esto, creo un objeto Date con los valores del select.
                //Ya con el objeto Date, lo muestro en pantalla con date.InnerHTML() y hecho
            }

            function cargarNumeroDias(){
                let comboDia=document.getElementById("dia");
                var length = comboDia.options.length;
                for (i = comboDia.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    comboDia.remove(i);
                }

                let anio = document.getElementById("anio").value;
                let mes = document.getElementById("mes").value;

                let numeroDias=calcularDiasMes(anio, mes); //Con esto cojo el número de días para el mes y el año en concreto

                for (let i= 1; i <= numeroDias; i++) {
                    let option=document.createElement("option"); //Con esto le creo la etiqueta option
                    option.setAttribute("value", i); //Con esto le seteo el valor (pero de forma interna, el usuario no ve este valor)
                    let optionText=document.createTextNode(i); //Con esto le seteo la opción que yo como usuario veo
                    option.appendChild(optionText); //Con esto meto el optionText en la etiqueta Option
                    comboDia.appendChild(option); //Con esto meto el option en el comboDia, que es lo que está vinculado a la etiqueta  
                }
            }

            function calcularDiasMes(anio, mes) {
                let numeroDias = -1;

                switch (mes) {
                    case '1':
                    case '3':
                    case '5':
                    case '7':
                    case '8':
                    case '10':
                    case '12':
                        numeroDias = 31;
                        break;
                    case '4':
                    case '6':
                    case '9':
                    case '11':
                        numeroDias = 30;
                        break;
                    case '2':
                        if ((anio % 4 == 0 && anio % 100 != 0) || (anio % 100 == 0 && anio % 400 == 0)) { //Con esto sé si es bisiesto o no
                            numeroDias = 29;
                        } else {
                            numeroDias = 28;
                        }
                        break;
                }

                return numeroDias;
            }

            window.onload = cargarPagina; //Para que esta función se cargue cuando se inicia la página
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Te queda por hacer mostrar la fecha total, pero de eso ya te encargarás tu ;)